# How to group, count and map date ranges?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on a booking model where items can be rented for an arbitrary period of time and each item has a maximum capacity of bookings per day (which is basically the quantity  of an item). Obviously, I want to check whether an item is available for booking or if the maximum capacity has already been reached prior a booking. I thought about creating a method in the `Booking` model which returns an array of objects with all **un**available dates and items, so that the desired output is:

```
[ {rentalitem_id: 1, unavailable: '01-03-2018'},
  {rentalitem_id: 2, unavailable: '02-03-2018'},
  {rentalitem_id: 1, unavailable: '01-03-2018'} ]
```

I could then render the method with JSON in order to access it in my frontend (Vue.js) where I could simply disable all dates for the according items. Of course I would also validate whether the date is available or not in the backend while processing the booking.

**First question**: What do you think of the idea? Maybe there are more elegant solutions how to achieve this?

So far the method in my bookings model that I wrote looks like the following:

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord

 ...

   scope :future_bookings, -> (time) { where("rental_start >= ?", time) }

 ...

   def self.item_unavailable
      sorted_booking = future_bookings(Time.now).map do |booking|
         { rentalitem_id: booking.rentalitem_id,
           dates: ((booking.rental_start.to_date..booking.rental_end.to_date).map{ |date| date.strftime("%b %d %y") }).to_a }
      end
      merged_bookings = sorted_booking.group_by{ |key| key[:rentalitem_id]}.each do |_, value|
          value.map!{ |arr| arr[:dates] }
      end
   end
end
```

So, basically I map over all future bookings creating a variable consiting of the `rentalitem_id` and all dates between `rental_start` and `rental_end`. After that, I group those results by the `rentalitem_id`, so that `merged_bookings` now returns all dates on which an item is booked:

```
# { 1=>[["Feb 28 18", "Mar 01 18", "Mar 02 18", "Mar 03 18"], ["Mar 01 18", "Mar 02 18", "Mar 03 18", "Mar 04 18", "Mar 05 18"]], 2=>[["Mar 01 18", "Mar 02 18"], ["Mar 02 18", "Mar 03 18"], ["Mar 02 18", "Mar 03 18", "Mar 04 18"]] }
```

The idea was to count all intersecting dates across the arrays and return the date when it reaches the maximum capacity for the according rentalitem, whereas the maximum capacity should be queried from the rentalitem model. However, I'm stuck here and tried everything I could imagine to perfom this action. I thought about using `inject` to return the values which are unavailable, but before that I would need to count the intersecting dates?

Let's suppose the first `rentalitem` has a maximum capacity of two bookings per day, than it should be unavailable for March 1st. Further, suppose the second `rentalitem` has a maximum capacity of three bookings per day. Hence it should be unavailable for March 2nd following the example.

I would highly appreciate some help here :-)

Answer (score 1):

i'd create a `RentalItemAvailability` class, passing `rental_item` and the date, in order to check availability for a given date, instead of trying to make something really weird figuring out how to achieve the same by a range of dates... something like:

```
class RentalItemAvailability
  delegate :maximum_capacity_per_day, :bookins, to: :@rental_item

  def initialize(rental_item, date)
    @rental_item = rental_item
    @date = date
  end

  def available?
    bookings_on_date < maximum_capacity_per_day
  end

  def bookins_on_date
    bookins
     .where('rental_start between :date and :date and rental_end between :date and :date', @date).count
  end
end
```

That way you can validate each day and mark `rental_item` as available/not available

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I actually thought about your suggested approach in the first place and I think it's definitely the best way to validate a booking on a server side. However, in order to make this work on the client side I would need to do one of the following options: A) Do an API call everytime a user changes the dates. B) Render all future bookings upon page load and use Vue to evaluate whether a date is available or not. Which approach would you suggest for the front end?

Comment: I'd go for option A, and maybe look for a way to cache certain data (using redis, for example)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you asking to modify `item_unavailable` to return a count for each item/date. To do that, you would *probably* want to build a hash within ruby based on the item_id, which contains the dates and counts. Something like this:

```
{
  1: {
    "Feb 28 18": 1,
    "Mar 01 18": 2
  }
}
```

An alternative approach would be to store a separate booking for each date (instead of having a begin and end date). That would end up being a greater number of records, but I believe it would be a more intuitive approach.
An example of querying for results similar to the hash above:

```
future_bookings.group(:rentalitem_id, :date).count
# {[1, "date_from_db"]=>2, [2, "date2_from_db"]=>1}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Building a hash which contains dates and counts instead of unavailable dates is also a good idea. I'm gonna play around with this and see where it takes me. I don't really like the idea to store separate dates though, even the query might be more straightforward.